# Use PowerShell to destroy source code marked for deletion in TFS, is this possible?

Tags: rest, powershell, tfs

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSAzM.png)

If you look at the picture, I have marked some sample files/source in VS2017 source Control Explorer as deleted, but TFS doesn't delete it automatically, you have to destroy it manually with the tf destroy command.

I wanted to make PowerShell use the TFS REST API to get source that has been marked for deletion, but looking through their API reference, I haven't found a way to do this, it doesn't seem like the API exposes that kind of information, but somehow Visual Studio 2017 is able to get it, so surely I should be able to?

I'm using TFS2017 Update 2, so this is api version 3.2.

Why I want to do this: We're running low on space and we have lots of team project collections with source marked for deletion. It would be very tedious to destroy everything manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have TFS Power Tools you can use this PowerShell script to destory all the deleted items (with `tf` and not with rest api, but it does the work, you don't need to do it manually):

```
$tfsServer = Get-TfsServer -name http://YOURTFSSERVER:PORT    
$destroyList = get-tfschilditem -item $/Root/ -server $tfsServer -Deleted -recurse | Where {$_.DeletionId -ne 0} 
foreach($item in $destroyList)
{
    $itemPath = '"' + $item.ServerItem + ";X" + $item.DeletionId + '"'
    tf destroy $itemPath /i /startcleanup
}
```

Comment: Found a similar solution the day before you posted this, using Power Tools 2015. Hopefully this helps out someone in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no REST APIs for this. You will have to use [`tf.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control?view=vsts).